# How can I redirect http to https using traefik?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am running into a slight issue with redirecting http to https traffic with Traefik. So far, my https router with acme is working fine, but I have two problems I am try to overcome.

- I have to manually specify `https://domain` to go through the the https route. Otherwise it tries to go through the http route and gets a 404.
- Even when I am manually typing in `https://domain` it works for the most part, but in some paths, for no reason, it will try to go via the http route, and gets a 404.

How can I make sure that the route is always using https for every path in the route whether https was typed into the address bar?

The entrypoints are name `http` and `https`. My partially working setup:

```
- "traefik.enable=true"
- traefik.port=8000
- traefik.backend=myapp
- traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`sub.mydomain.com`)
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp.entrypoints=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
# redir http to https
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.rule=Host(`sub.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix({p:.+})"
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.entrypoints=https"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.myapp-secure.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp.middlewares=myapp-secure"
- "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.tls=true"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the below labels on the traefik service itself and all the HTTP traffic will be redirected to HTTPS

```
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=https_redirect
```

More info and full examples for using Traefik can be found [here](https://medium.com/@wshihadeh/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32)

Comment: Does anybody know whether or not these labels may cause conflicts for the Let's Encrypt `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` challenging in `http` when you're redirecting to `https`? More in detail [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/redirect-to-https-causing-problems/60531/10)

Comment: if you're not auto exposing your containers, YOU NEED TO ADD `traefik.enabled=true` here as well. Got stuck for an hour debugging all kinds of redirect setups because of my `exposedbydefault=false`

Answer (score 7):

Also if you configure it using commands, instead of labels, you can add this

```
 - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure"
 - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60513369/10087707), adding the following should only redirect for requests not matching the ACME http validation for Letsencrypt certs

```
"traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`) && !PathPrefix(`/.well-known/acme-challenge/`)"
```